# @Bean not applicable to field

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm learning Spring, doing MKYong's tutorial, and I'm stuck in Spring DI - http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-di-via-setter-method/.

Tried to change it to Java configuration, but @Bean annotation gives me error as in the top of topic.

IOutputGenerator.java:

```
public Interface IOutputGenerator{
    public void generateOutput();
}
```

CsvOutputGenerator.java:

```
public class CsvOutputGenerator.java implements IOutputGenerator{
    public void generateOutput(){
        System.out.println("CSV Output gen");
    }
}
```

AppConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig{
    @Bean
    public CsvOutputGenerator csvOutputGenerator;
}
```

And IntelliJ highlight me this "@Bean" annotation as wrong with message: @Bean not applicable to field.

Anyone?

Comment: Word of advice: don't use such dodgy and outdated sources for learning Spring, the official documentation is polished to perfection and up-to-date. Apart from the "dry" but exhaustive [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/) they have cookbook-style [guides](https://spring.io/guides) if you want to jump straight into action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not declare as `Bean` a field.

Instead, you should have something like:

```
@Bean
public CsvOutputGenerator csvOutputGenerator() {
    return new CsvOutputGenerator();
}
```

which is the corresponding to:

```
<bean id="CsvOutputGenerator" class="com.mkyong.output.impl.CsvOutputGenerator" />
```

In fact, an instantiated Java object should be declared as Bean, and this object would then be available for Autowire in other beans.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I see this now.